# lensGlass=false doesn't seem to work in pst-optic

Tags: pst-optic

Consider the following example:

```
%%xelatex
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-optic}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-text}

\begin{document}


\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-3)(8.5,3)
\rput(0,0){\lens[focus=3.333,OA=-10,AB=2,XO=2,xLeft=-8.5,xRight=8.5,rayColor=red,lensGlass=false]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The option `lensGlass=false` replaces the lens by this gray rectangle. How can I configure it that the lense is not shown at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this version](http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/TeXnik/tex/generic/pst-optic/) of `pstricks.tex`. It knows the optional argument `onlyrays`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,crop]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-optic}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-8.5,-3)(8.5,3)
\rput(0,0){\lens[focus=3.333,OA=-10,AB=2,XO=2,xLeft=-8.5,xRight=8.5,
                 rayColor=red,onlyrays]}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]